# How to "peep" if Flux has exception?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I use Spring Webflux with Tomcat servlet container (*spring-boot-starter-web* + *spring-boot-starter-webflux*) and I would like to get the following result:

If flux of fails immediately, I would like sent to client response code 400

Otherwise, I would like to sent response code 200 and stream the flux

I tried different solutions, but no one works. `v1` and `v2` does not sent expected response code if failure scenario, `v3` does not stream output is happy scenario.

I would like to "peep" exception on `failFlux` and trigger the exception before response code 200 is sent

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public class X {
 Flux<String> happyFlux = Flux.generate(s -> s.next("x"));  
 Flux<String> failFlux = Flux.error(new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST));

 //ok: flux is streamed

 @RequestMapping("/v1/happy")
 Flux<String> v1Happy() {
    return happyFlux;
 }

 //nok: http status code is 200

 @RequestMapping("/v1/fail")
 Flux<String> v1Fail() {
    return failFlux;
 }

 //ok: flux is streamed

 @RequestMapping("/v2/happy")
 Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<String>>> v2Happy() {
    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body(happyFlux));
 }

 //nok: http status code is 200

 @RequestMapping("/v2/fail")
 Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<String>>> v2Fail() {
    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body(failFlux));
 }

 //nok: flux is not streamed but collected on server side

 @RequestMapping("/v3/happy")
 Mono<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> v3Happy() {
    return happyFlux.collectList().map(ResponseEntity::ok);
 }

 //ok: http status code is 400

 @RequestMapping("/v3/fail")
 Mono<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> v3Fail() {
    return failFlux.collectList().map(ResponseEntity::ok);
 }
```

PS. What is interesting, `v1` and `v2` works with netty (only *spring-boot-starter-webflux*).

#### Update

I think "peeping" Flux is impossible. What I really is better Flux handling in Spring for servlet stack: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17440

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? When is that exception being thrown? What exception is that? Could you provide the logs after adding a `log()` operator after the flux returned by the controller? Could you show an example of HTTP request and resposne (with headers and body)?

Comment: @BrianClozel, I rewrote my question completely, I hope now is more clear

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to use collectList() as that defeats the entire purpose of producing a Stream. 
I believe you should be getting a 500 in case of exception message.

For instance, check the below code.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> listPeople(ServerRequest request) {
    int error = 10/0;
    Flux<Person> peopleFlux = this.repository.allPeople();
    peopleFlux = withDelay(peopleFlux);

    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).body(peopleFlux, Person.class);


}
```

The statement

```
int error = 10/0;
```

causes a 500 exception and in the client I do get 500. If I comment out the error statement then I get a 200. 
So, please share you code if you are not getting 500. Please note that if the error happens after the server has started returning individual events in the stream then it will not be a 500. 
You should rather use HTTP 207. https://httpstatuses.com/207

Comment: Please take a look on my question again - I rewrote it completely. I fully agree that `collectList` is wrong way - I just present my experiments

Comment: @michaldo I do agree that the behavior has to be consistent. I would be more aligned towards a success code as we never know which event in the Flux may error out.